# Bootsrap Carousel Text not sliding

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I'm using the exact clone of this script http://jsfiddle.net/uktry43n/2/ but I'm having problem with text not getting slide. How can I slide the whole content along with the images?

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
    });

$('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
            var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
        $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can append text into slide item with images

For example, slider item template:

```
<div><!-- slide 1 -->
  <img src="">
  <p>text</p>
</div>

<div><!-- slide 2 -->
  <img src="">
  <p>text2</p>
</div>
```

See on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uktry43n/4/

Comment: @MD SHOEB MIRZA what if use two sliders, first for images, second for content. And start both at the same time? And when control button clicked, move both sliders